# How can I save the output from loop to CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to save the sample output from this loop to CSV

```
[(16.0, 'thermionic vacuum diode device'), (4.0, 'adjustable electrodes')]
[(16.0, 'thermionic vacuum diode device'), (4.0, 'adjustable electrodes')]
[(9.0, 'heat transfer device')]
```

This output are generated from

```
def write_csv():
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        text = row
        r.extract_keywords_from_sentences(text)
        r.get_ranked_phrases()
        score = r.get_ranked_phrases_with_scores()
        new_df = pd.DataFrame({'col':score})
        new_df = df.append(df)
        #print(score)
    df.to_csv("test_score_2.csv")
```

When I call `def write_csv()`, the CSV file contains only the last line, but I want to save all rows to the CSV file.

Is any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your df at each step.

```
def write_csv():
    data = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        text = row
        r.extract_keywords_from_sentences(text)
        r.get_ranked_phrases()
        score = r.get_ranked_phrases_with_scores()
        data.append({'col': score})

     df = pd.DataFrame(data)
     df.to_csv("test_score_2.csv")
```

Your append logic might have worked if there was a `df` variable in the first place. However, there is none.

Remember, assigning a value to a variable wipes whatever it used to point to. You're **re**-assigning the variable to point to a new object in memory.